# Idiomatic way to use urlize filter with blocktrans in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, gettext, django-template-filters

I recently discovered a neat trick to avoid polluting the gettext translation files for Django with unnecessary markup. If you want to make an email address clickable, you can use the `urlize` filter after the `trans` string argument, like this:

```
{% trans "Contact us at foo@bar.com"|urlize %}
```

Is there any way to apply the same trick to the result of a `blocktrans` tag?

Answer (score 4):

There is a `filter` block tag that lets you apply one or more filters to the contents of a block, so you can use it like this:

```
{% filter urlize %}
  {% blocktrans %}Contact us at at foo@bar.com{% endblocktrans %}
{% endfilter %}
```

See [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#filter).